# Showing $\Gamma\left(x+1\right) \ge x^{x/2}$, when $x\ge2$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, gamma-function

It is easy to show that $(2n)! \ge (2n)^n$.

Indeed, if we have $ 1\le k\le n$, for integer $k,n$ , we can write:
$$
\begin{aligned}
0\lt n+\frac{1}{2}-k &\le n - \frac{1}{2} \\
\left(n+\frac{1}{2}-k\right)^2 &\le \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \\
k\cdot(2n-k+1)&\ge2n
\end{aligned}
$$
and so
$$
(2n)! = 1\cdot2\cdots (2n) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} {k\cdot(2n-k+1)} \ge (2n)^n
$$
A variation of the above argument can be used to prove the statement for odd integers.

Is this statment true for all real $x\ge2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$f(x) =  \log \Gamma(x + 1) - \frac{x \log(x)}{2} = \log(x) + \log \Gamma(x) - \frac{x \log(x)}{2}$$

We will prove that $f$ is a convex function with $f(2) = 0$ and $f'(2) > 0$. Using the [subderivative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) of convex functions we then get 
$$f(x) \geq f(2) + (x - 2) f'(2) \ge 0 \qquad \text{for } x \ge 2,$$
which is what we wanted to prove.

The first two derivatives of $f$ are
$$\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \psi(x) + \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\log(x)}{2} \\
f''(x) &= \psi'(x) - \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{2x}
\end{align*},$$
where $\psi$ resp. $\psi'$ are the di- resp. trigamma function. We will now use the formulae from [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm).

First of all, formula 6.3.2 tells us
$$f'(2) = \psi(2) - \frac{\log(2)}{2} = 1 - \gamma - \frac{\log(2)}{2} = 0.076... > 0$$

To prove convexity, we will show $f''(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \ge 2$. From 6.4.10 we get the representation
$$\psi'(x) = \sum \limits_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(x + k)^2} = \frac{1}{x^2} + \sum \limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x + k)^2}.$$

Now it only remains to prove the inequality
$$\sum \limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x + k)^2} \ge \frac{1}{2x}.$$
As pointed out by Jack Lam in the comments (many thanks!) this can be proven using telescoping:
$$\sum \limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x + k)^2} \ge \sum \limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x + k)(x + k + 1)} = \sum \limits_{k = 1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{x + k} - \frac{1}{x + k + 1}\right) =  \frac{1}{x + 1} \ge \frac{1}{2x}.$$

Comment: Filling in for Jack D'Aurizio here XD


$\displaystyle \frac{1}{(x+k)^2} > \frac{1}{(x+k)(x+k+1)}$ which then telescopes giving $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x+k)^2} > \frac{1}{x+1} > \frac{1}{2x}$

Comment: @JackLam Thanks a lot! I was thinking way too complicated here.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a source for the proofs of identities 6.3.2 and 6.4.10?

Comment: I don't know any sources. I guess you need to play around with the definition of the gamma function, differentiation under the integral sign, interschanging series and sums etc..

Comment: Both of the identities follow directly from $\psi(z+1) = \psi(z) + \frac{1}{z}$. See for example http://129.81.170.14/~vhm/formula_html/final10.pdf, bottom of page 2, Theorem 1.2. $~~~$ The recursive $\psi(z+1) = \psi(z) + \frac{1}{z}$ itself is easily derived, see e.g. the very first section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers titled "Relation to Harmonic Numbers"

Comment: The first link "final10.pdf" above is a note from Tulane University, found by googling the key words "derive digamma identity", the 7th or 8th result on the first page.